# Class file for XYZ uses preview features of Java SE 17 Error

Tags: java, gradle, incompatibility

I'm trying to make a scheduled Whatsapp sender and thought of using Auties00 WhatsApp4J library.
After creating a new project and adding the code to create a connection, following error occures:

```
error: class file for .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.auties00/whatsappweb4j/3.3.1/d8c9b37af703062b20b137100d8dc11abe8a27f7/whatsappweb4j-3.3.1.jar(/it/auties/whatsapp/api/Whatsapp.class) uses preview features of Java SE 17.
  (use --enable-preview to allow loading of class files which contain preview features)
1 error
```

I'm currently using JDK 19 with Gradle 7.6.1 so I'm confused why it's throwing the afore mentioned error.

I tried to upgrade from the TLS JDK 17 to JDK19 but the error persists.
Adding the --enable-preview flag didn't work either.
[This](https://github.com/Auties00/Whatsapp4j) is Auties00 WhatsApp4J library

My build.gradle looks like this:

```xml
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '19'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'com.github.auties00:whatsappweb4j:3.3.1'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And my main class like this:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import it.auties.whatsapp.api.Whatsapp;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Whatsapp.webBuilder()
                .newConnection()
                .build()
                .addLoggedInListener(() -> System.out.println("Connected"))
                .addDisconnectedListener(reason -> System.out.printf("Disconnected: %s%n", reason))
                .connect()
                .join();
    }
}
```

Comment: I took a look into readme.md from your lib and found following text: "Java version
This library was built for Java 17, the latest LTS. Remember to enable preview features as they are required. If you don't know how, there are many tutorials available online. Please don't open any issue because of this." May be you need jdk 17 instead of jdk19 or you have to compile your code into language level of java 17.

Comment: @Reporter I tried enabling preview features with adding
```tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs += '--enable-preview'
}
tasks.withType(Test) {
    jvmArgs += "--enable-preview"
}
```
to my build.gradle file but the error still persists:(
Shouldn't java be anyway backwards compatible?

Comment: from documentation about [Preview Features](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/language/preview-language-and-vm-features.html#GUID-5A82FE0E-0CA4-4F1F-B075-564874FE2823__GUID-54A1B35D-0818-46F5-8CEE-5E8D79A87866): "***Note:** Code that uses preview features from an older release of the Java SE Platform will not necessarily compile or run on a newer release.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to compile the project. Apparently are preview features not back compatible within Java. Thanks to [@user16320675](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16320675/user16320675)'s help I found this on [Gradle Docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:feature_preview):

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    options.compilerArgs += "--enable-preview"
}

tasks.withType(Test).configureEach {
    jvmArgs += "--enable-preview"
}

tasks.withType(JavaExec).configureEach {
    jvmArgs += "--enable-preview"
}
```

I added the snipped to my build.gradle file and had to change my projects jdk from 19 to 17, because only with version 17 the preview features I needed were available.